# iphone , how to change the systemwide volume?

Tags: iphone

all,  I want play sound even the iPhone in mute mode, but the method : [AVAudioPlayer setVolume] does not effect if the device is in mute mode ...

is it possible  have some way to change the systemwide volume ?

thanks for your help ...

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to let the user set the system volume is with an MPVolumeView.  The whole point of the mute button is that applications cannot play sounds, and there is no sanctioned way to override that.

Comment: if the user were in a meeting he probably be pretty pissed off if the phone suddenly played some track despite being on mute lol.

Comment: +1 for letting me know that there is in fact a way to set the system volume. Up til now I thought that impossible!

Comment: um... the app purpose is a alarm app that let use can fire alarm notification anytime ...

 MPVolumeView probably can be use for this purpose , but I am not sure how to adjust the volume by program ...

Comment: You should be able to have the alarm trigger vibration.